# MemoryStream in response alongside other parameters possible?

Tags: javascript, c#, memorystream

in my project (Backend: c# - Frontend: JavaScript) I want to send a csv file as MemoryStream in a response object to the frontend.

At first I sent back a HttpResponse object which worked. But now I would like to send other information back, alongside the MemoryStream.

Something like this:

```
{
 Stream = stream,
 Succeded = true,
 Messages = "text"
}
```

Is this even possible? It didn't work for me, using Axios for the fetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to send any objects that can be read as JSON. Your CSV will eventually be converted to a string before the response gets send. Your backend will not stream the CSV but rather the response is send all at once.

You could try to serialize your object to a JSON string and return that string in the HttpResponse. Then you could read it in your frontend.

Comment: Serializing sounds interesting. I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: Found that in the description of WCF: "To stream data, the parameter that holds that data must be the only parameter in the message.": [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/stream?redirectedfrom=MSDN) - So serializing is the way to go.